# Reading data from NodeJs Serialport

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, serial-port

I would like to be able to read data received by the ascii command sent.

Below is the code that sends command to my lock controller

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var SerialPort = require('serialport');


/* GET home page */
router.get('/', function(request, response){


    SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
      ports.forEach(function(port) {
        console.log(port.comName);
        console.log(port.pnpId);
        console.log(port.manufacturer);
      });
    });


    var port = new SerialPort("COM5", {
  baudRate: 38400
});

    port.on('open', function() {
        // NodeJS v4 and earlier
        port.write(new Buffer('status1', 'ascii'), function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
          }
          console.log('message written');

        });
    });

    // open errors will be emitted as an error event 
    port.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error: ', err.message);
    });

});

// Important
module.exports = router;
```

In the doc, it mentions the use of parsers to try and read data, https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#serialportparsers--object but I am not sure how to implement it, and I would want to execute after the command `status1` has been written.

Essentially logs the response of the command succesfully written to the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some peculiarities.
You can open port on application start and reconnect on port close or open port on each request. It defines how work with data flow. If you send request to port then answer can contain data of previous requests (more than one). You can ignore this problem (if answer is short and request interval is enough large) or send request with assign id and search answer with this id.

```
SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
        console.log(port.comName, port.pnpId, port.manufacturer); // or console.log(port)
    });
});

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    function sendData(code, msg) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.write(msg);
        console.log(msg);   
    }

    var port = new SerialPort("COM5", {
        baudRate: 38400
    });

    port.on('open', function() {
        port.write(Buffer.from('status1', 'ascii'), function(err) {
            if (err) 
                return sendData(500, err.message);

            console.log('message written');
        });
    });

    var buffer = '';
    port.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk;
        var answers = buffer.split(/\r?\n/); \\ Split data by new line character or smth-else
        buffer = answers.pop(); \\ Store unfinished data

        if (answer.length > 0) 
            sendData(200, answer[0]);
    });

    port.on('error', function(err) {
        sendData(500, err.message);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: thank you. I ran into the following error      on line    var answers = buffer.split('\n'); \\ Split data by new line character or smth-else SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Change `'\n'` to `/\r?\n/` (I use another delimiter).

Comment: Thank you. How would i be able to verify wheter or not i have received a message from the controller in terms of the response to the command issue (this will also tell if the command was succesfully received and understood)?

Comment: Controller can send `ACK`-reply on each correct request, but I think that it's too much in your case.

Comment: Each time when device on com-port receive message then device send `ACK`-reply (short message) immediately if request is correct. And some time ago send `result`-reply (it can be long text sended by some chunk). On node-side if you receive `ACK` then wait `result`. If `ACK` is not received then smth wrong with port.

Comment: thank you for clarification. Would it be it possible to do so at the code level?