# NodeJs: Read data from COM serial port

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read data from the device connected to COM port. I am able to connect to the port and able to get information about the device using package SerialPort (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport).

I am facing an issue when I am trying to read data from the device.
Please find my code below:

```
 var port = new SerialPort("COM5", {
        baudRate: 38400
    });
 port.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
    });
port.on('error', function(err) {
        sendData(500, err.message);
    });
```

On trying to read the data the control is going to error function and I am getting the response as

> Access Denied

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**NOTE:** I am able to open the port but facing issue to read the data from the port.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080649/reading-data-from-nodejs-serialport

Comment: @ThanveerShah I have gone through it. I am able to open and write to port but not able to read.

Answer (score 0):

As i was working on systems like that at c. We have to code a driver
to handle serial ports. Maybe it can cause because of operation systems security, you can try to use as admin or write a c driver to read the data and send that to your nodejs app is another way.