# How to get the data from serial port and store it in a variable using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, serial-port

I have just started using serialport libraries on Nodejs, and I am not sure how to read the data and store it in a variable, so as to use that data later on to make comparisons or decisions based on it.

This is the the code I have come up with till now, its very basic but this is what I could manage

```
 const SerialPort = require("serialport");
  const Readline = require("@serialport/parser-readline");

  const port = new SerialPort("COM5", {baudRate: 9600 });
  const parser = new Readline('/r/n');
  port.pipe(parser);
  //setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
  parser.on("data", (line) => console.log(line));
```

Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080649/reading-data-from-nodejs-serialport) might help.